# How would you say "he does not take criticism well" in Cantonese and in Mandarin?

Tags: mandarin, cantonese, topolect

How would you say this in Cantonese and how would you say this in Mandarin?

Comment: This is essentially a translation question, which is off topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mandarin parts.

> 他无法接受批评.
>
> 他不太接受批评.
>
> 他很反感别人批评.

Cantonese Parts

> 佢唔擅长听其他人嘅意见
>
> 距五擅长听人意见
>
> 佢最唔叻听人意见了
>
> “距都”钟意听人地讲

Answer (score 4):

Mandarin

```
他很介意被批评。
```

Cantonese

```
佢好介意畀人讲。
```

Comment: These seem to mean "He minds very much being criticized." which is a little different

Comment: This was the second closest. Even though it's not exactly the translation, it's very much close in meaning and spirit, and will be useful in future conversations. Thanks for the contribution.

Answer (score 3):

In Mandarin, we can say:

他听不进别人（对他）的批评。

他很反感别人（对他）的批评。

他不喜欢别人（对他）的批评。

他受不了别人（对他）的批评。

他很难听取别人（对他）的批评。

他很难接受别人（对他）的批评。

他不善于听取别人（对他）的批评。

他不善于接受别人（对他）的批评。

他不能正确对待别人（对他）的批评。

他不能虚心接受别人（对他）的批评。

Sorry, I don't speak Cantonese. I hope someone who speaks Cantonese can translate them.

Comment: which is cantonese?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about that. They are all in Mandarin. Thanks. Answer edited.

Comment: I think 他不善于听取别人（对他）的批评。 is the best so far.

Comment: The "别人（对他）的" is redundant and the phrase "不善于" sounds more like written Chinese than spoken Mandarin (or spoken Cantonese, if that matters). But I agree that "他不善于听取批评" is a good translation *in written Chinese*.

Comment: +1 for Mandarin

Answer (score 1):

Mandarin : 他不能很好的接受(别人的)批评。

Sorry I don't know about Cantonese.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer for the mandarin part.

```
他不在乎别人的评价。
```

For the Cantonese i can say you it sounds more or less,

```
Kui m zayi kue ta yen hua kui.
```

but i don't know how to write it.

Comment: err... 不在乎 means don't mind; don't care. Which is not what the asker means.